# Connecting to openproject installed on a remote fedora20 server

Tags: apache, fedora20, openproject

I just installed *OpenProject* using package installation on a *fedora20*.
Everything seems OK. I can call the Apache Server with

> http://185.82.22.144:80

But I cannot connect to OpenProject.

```
<http://185.82.22.144:80/OpenProject>
```

Ends up with a message saying:

> 'not found on this server'

Is there a means to check which applications are installed on an Apache Server, something like Tomcat manager?

Answer (score 0):

sorry to all, I just forgot the

```
openProject configure
```

Step, because I suggested it to be included in the package installation.
Now

http://185.82.22.144:80

points successfully to my openProject Installation.

peter
Do, Germany